# HTTP status code 500 when querying an API from a C# program, except the API works

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I need to use another company's API to query data using POST requests.
The API works (= I receive all the data with no errors) when I query it from the swagger website using the UI, but when I do it from my C# program I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Where should I be looking for the problem ? Is there a way to get a more detailed error message ?

Edit (added code) :

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace credex_distribution_offers_to_interfaces
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string jsonMediaType = "application/json";

        static void Main()
        {
            FetchJSONAndInsertToDB();
        }

        private static bool FetchJSONAndInsertToDB()
        {
            var baseServiceUrl = new Uri("a valid url");

            Root rootObject;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(jsonMediaType));

                try
                {
                    string token = FetchToken(httpClient, baseServiceUrl);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                try
                {
                    rootObject = FetchDistributionLookupOffers(httpClient, baseServiceUrl, 29612, 29613, 29614, 29617, 29621);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // database related stuff...
            // ...

            return true;
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class MortgageForDistributionLookupInputDto
        {
            public int[] OfferNumbers { get; set; }
        }
        
        private static Root FetchDistributionLookupOffers(HttpClient aHttpClient, Uri aBaseServiceUrl, params int[] aOfferNumbers)
        {
            var input = new MortgageForDistributionLookupInputDto()
            {
                OfferNumbers = aOfferNumbers
            };

            var lookup = aHttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(aBaseServiceUrl, "v1/MortgageDetails/InvestorLookupOffers"), PayloadFor(input)).Result;

            if (lookup.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Fetching investor lookup offers failed with HTTP status code '" + lookup.StatusCode + "' : " + lookup.ReasonPhrase + "}");
            }

            var obj = ValueFor<Root>(lookup.Content);
            return obj;
        }

        private static HttpContent PayloadFor<T>(T aObject)
        {
            return new StringContent(aObject.SerializeJson(), Encoding.UTF8, jsonMediaType);
        }

        private static T ValueFor<T>(HttpContent aHttpContent)
        {
            //var content = aHttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return aHttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result.DeSerializeJson<T>();
        }

        private static string FetchToken(HttpClient aHttpClient, Uri aBaseServiceUrl)
        {
            var login = new LoginRequest()
            {
                UserName = "some user name",
                Password = "some password"
            };

            var authResult = aHttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(aBaseServiceUrl, "api/Login"), PayloadFor(login)).Result;

            if (authResult.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Fetching authentication token failed. Reason : " + authResult.StatusCode + " -> " + authResult.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            return authResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim('"');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can upload the code if needed.

Comment: Hi @Lucas, I'd like to recommend to provide more details, as for now the question sounds too wide, because of which it's hard to provide an answer. Btw do you have some authentication there, how does the controller that handles the route look like, or what kind of requests were working, and which not... Any detail might be useful

Comment: Hi, you may try to query the api using postman or something like fiddler

Comment: @JustShadow Yes, I do need to authenticate to retrieve data. I first need to query a *token* that I have to add to the ```DefaultHeaders``` property of my ```HttpClient```. If the token is not valid, the API returns a 500. But that doesn't seem to be the case, because the queried token **is** valid (I checked). I'm going to add the code to my post